# How to forbid rewriting data if it exists

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I add user in table "users" after authorization. Also I will add to this user some values, which I don't want to be overrided.

```
ref.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).setValue(["username": "MyName"])
```

Rules

```
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "users": {
      ".write": "!root.child('users/'+auth.uid).exists()",
      ".read":true,
      "positive": {
        ".read": true,
          ".write":false,
      },
      "negative": {
        ".read": true,
          ".write":false,
      },
    }
  }
}
```

removes old data and put a new.

I want to write rule on server side, which will ignore setting value if it already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `updateChildValues()`, the properties you specify will be updated:

```
ref.child("users")
   .child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)
   .updateChildValues(["username": "MyName"])
```

See the [Firebase documentation on updating specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Your rules will not work, since you cannot take away a permission that you've given on a higher level in the tree. See the [Firebase documentation on the cascading of permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade).

To ensure a user always has certain properties, use a rule on the user's node:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
      ".write": "newData.hasChildren(['certain', 'properties])",
```

Comment: Does this prevent data being written to a node where data already exists?

Comment: Nope. That would be `!data.exists()`.

Comment: Very strange that we can't control data on server side. Yes, you solution is working. Not as I wanted to, by let it be.

Comment: Frank, please, correct this line "newData.hasChildren(['certain', 'properties'])"

Comment: Done. Note that there's an edit link so that anyone can fix such typos.